# Which pairs of $\mathbb{N}_0$ satisfy my equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find all integer solutions  $\left(n,k\right)\in \mathbb{N}^2_0$ for an equation `4.5 == (n*k + n - 1)*0.1` and then make a `ListPlot` of all the pairs.

Using

```
ContourPlot[4.5 == (n*k + n - 1)*0.1, {n, 0, 45}, {k, 0, 45}]
```

I find a continuous solution, but I can't seem to be able to get only the `Integer` solutions.

Comment: The reason why you didn't find integer solutions is because you probably used Solve with your original equation, where the numbers are Reals and not integers.
For fixing the problem, you either reshape your equation to have MMA working with Integers (as in my answer) or you Rationalize the equation (as in @kglr answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
coords = {n, k} /. 
  Solve[{Rationalize[4.5 == (n*k + n - 1)*0.1], n >= 0, k >= 0}, {n, k}, Integers]
```

> {{1, 45}, {2, 22}, {23, 1}, {46, 0}}

```
ContourPlot[4.5 == (n*k + n - 1)*0.1, {n, 0, 46}, {k,0, 46}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@coords}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! But the solution includes negative Integers. Why the use of `Rationalize`?

Comment: @DPF see my comment to your original question, it's explained there :)

Comment: Very good! I did't see it in the first place...

Answer (score 4):

```
Solve[45 == (n*k + n - 1) && n >= 0 && k >= 0, {n, k}, Integers]
```

> {{n -> 1, k -> 45}, {n -> 2, k -> 22}, {n -> 23, k -> 1}, {n -> 46, 
>     k -> 0}}

For the plot:

```
ListPlot[{n, k} /. sol]
```

Comment: Thank you! I extended the question to $\mathbb{N}^2_0$ to include also 0 as a possible solution.

Comment: You're welcome. See new edit for including the 0.